# Keycode method works in emulator but not on actual device?

Tags: android

Why in the world does my `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` work in my emulator but not in my physical device?  I am using a KEYCODE event for my SearchView to press enter when the SearchView window opens.  It works in my emulator but it does not in my physical device.  Why?

```
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
        }
    }).start();
```